# VimL: VSPLIT with width specified as a function of total width

Tags: vim, viml

I want to write a vim script that opens a new window with vsplit, where the width of the new window is equal to the total number of columns minus 90.

The result would be, the current window would be 90 columns wide (to view 80 cols of code + gutter) and the new vsplit would occupy whatever part of the screen is left over.

If I understand vsplit correctly, :vsplit 90 specifies the window being created should be 90 columns. Is there a way to get the current number of columns in a window into a variable?

```
let cur_cols = [insert magic here]
let win_width = cur_cols - 90
execute "vsplit ". win_width
```

Comment: `winwidth` will provide width (in columns) of the current split.  Try `:echo winwidth(0)`

Comment: this is the right answer if you want to submit it, i'll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `winwidth` to find width of window. `winwidth` returns width as the no. of characters window can accommodate. In your case, use

```
let cur_cols = winwidth(0)
```

Here the parameter `0` refers to current widow. For more information,

```
:help winwidth
:help :vsplilt
```